# Calculate 95%CI for cumulative survival rate

Tags: confidence-interval, survival

For a research project, I am calculating a cumulative survival rate using the following formula:

> Cumulative survival<sub>t</sub> = survival proportion<sub>t-1</sub> *
> survival proportion<sub>t</sub>

So for example if we have a survival proportion of 90% (3 failures on 30 patients) at t=1 year and 95% (1 failure on 20 patients; already 3 failures at t=1 year and 7 lost to follow-up) at t=2 year, we will get a cumulative survival rate at t=2 year of 0,9*0,95=0,855, which equals to 85,5%.

Now my question is, is it possible to calculate a 95% CI for this cumulative rate?
I am not very familiar with statistics, and usually I only have to calculate a confidence interval for a proportion. But since this is cumulative, I am not sure what to do.

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Kaplan-Meier estimate of the survival curve. The common estimate of the variance uses [Greenwood's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplan%E2%80%93Meier_estimator#Statistical_considerations).  Assuming the estimate is approximately normal, the 95% CI would be the estimate plus or minus 1.96 times the square root of the estimated variance. Since S(t) should be between 0 and 1, you can also use the transformation log(-log(S(t))), which can be any real number. Make the approximate CI on that scale, then, transform back to the original scale. R will do these for you using predict.